# Invalid left-hand side in assignment but I am trying to assign a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a to do list with a edit mode and view mode.
I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at toggleEditMode (/script.js:8:18)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (/:14:54)
```

Full can be found at https://repl.it/@UCYT5040/Notekeeper, but the Javascript is below.

```js
editMode = true;
items = 1
function toggleEditMode() {
    console.log(editMode)
if (editMode == true) {
    editMode = false
    for (i = 0; i < items; i++) {
        document.getElementById('item' + (i + 1)) = "<h1 id=\"itemTitle" + (i + 1) + "\">" + document.getElementById('itemTitle' + (i + 1)).value + "</h1>"
        }
} else {
    editMode = true
    for (i = 0; i < items; i++) {
        document.getElementById('item' + (i + 1)) = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"itemTitle" + (i + 1) + "\" value=\"" + document.getElementById('itemTitle' + (i + 1)).innerHTML + "></input>"
        }
}
}
```

Comment: You can't do `document.getElementById('item' + (i + 1)) = . . .`. I think you may mean `document.getElementById('item' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = "<h1 id=\"itemTitle" + (i + 1) + "\">" + document.getElementById('itemTitle' + (i + 1)).value + "</h1>"`. You're trying to reassign a function call right now.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks for the help. Do you know why when I turn on edit mode it returns as `<div id="item1"><input type="text" id="itemTitle1" value="New Note"></h1></div>`? It should return as <div id="item1"><input type="text" id="itemTitle1" value="New Note"></input></div>.

Comment: A separate suggestion: always declare variables used in code and never rely on assignment to an identifier to create global variables for you. (I checked `script.js` in the codepen does not declare variables). Include `"use strict;"` as the first line in a script or function to have the compiler generate errors for missing variable declarations.